# How to give pagination in reading a e-pub format book (just like iBook shows pagination)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to display e-pub books, so I used a webview to display the e-pub book and I am able to display the book chapter-wise instead of page-wise. Can anyone please help me so that i can paginate the epub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To paginate ePub, you have to extensively use WebView and column layout with custom CSS. Here is a typical workflow for each chapter:

1. Create an in-memory or off-screen WebView component with required `width` and `height`;
2. Load a chapter HTML with injected `<script src="[local path]"></script>` tag;
3. JavaScipt code should enclose the whole content into one `div` tag using DHTML;
4. Also, JavaScript should inject CSS with a property `column-width` set for that `div` tag;
5. When WebKit engine completes rendering, you receive an event in JavaScript;
6. Once you get the event, it's time to count how many pages is in HTML: `clientWidth / width`.

Then, you can use the same technique to render ePub into UIViewController, but this time on screen. While rendering how many pages are in ePub, you may want to display a progress indicator.

Comment: Here i am also rendering the epub in to the uiwebview for portrait its loading but in landscape how can i load the content is there any way could u suggest me

Comment: @dineshprasanna Before rotation: find an element in the top left corner of the current page and remember its path and index in the parent container. After rotation: wait while the whole HTML chapter is loaded, then find location of the remembered element and perform `scrollTo`.

Comment: but how can i render the epub in landscape mode

Comment: @dineshprasanna Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Pages should be rendered separately for Portrait and Landscape modes. In the end of the day, you will have to operate with two separate indexes. And if you want two pages per screen in Landscape, then resize a WebView like `(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight)`.

Comment: Have you implemented landscape mode means could you share code